# ImageResizer Source Parameter not being accepted

Tags: c#, asp.net, imageresizer

I am trying to loop through jpeg images from a folder and feeding it to the dll using the below method but it throws me this error
Source may only be an instance of string, VirtualFile, IVirtualBitmapFile, HttpPostedFile, HttpPostedFileBase, Bitmap, Image, or Stream.
Parameter name: source

```
 foreach(FileInfo file in tempFolder.GetFiles())
        if (file.Exists == true)
        { //Skip unused file controls.

            //The resizing settings can specify any of 30 commands.. See http://imageresizing.net for details.
            //Destination paths can have variables like <guid> and <ext>, or 
            //even a santizied version of the original filename, like <filename:A-Za-z0-9>
            ImageResizer.ImageJob i = new ImageResizer.ImageJob(file, uploadFolder + "/<guid>.<ext>", new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings(
                        "width=2000;height=2000;format=jpg;mode=max"));
            i.CreateParentDirectory = true; //Auto-create the uploads directory.
            i.Build();
        }
        browser.Attributes["multiple"] = "multiple";
        Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
    }
```

Comment: instead of `file`, try `file.FullName`

Comment: I accept you as my god and true savior. Thanks a bunch :D

Comment: @Orifjon, can you post as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImageRsizer.ImageJob` accepts file path as parameter. Instead of providing `FileInfo` object, you need to pass `FullName` property of it. i.e.:

```
ImageResizer.ImageJob i = new ImageResizer.ImageJob(file.FullName, uploadFolder + "/<guid>.<ext>", new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings(
                    "width=2000;height=2000;format=jpg;mode=max"));
```